# "Segmentation fault: 11" when using fgets in C

Tags: c, macos, input, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am writing a command line tool in C to control UNDERTALE save files (cuz why not) and I keep getting a segmentation fault whenever I take input from the user.

Here is all my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define KILOBYTE 1024

/* The 'm()' is so i know what line the fault happens on */

void m(void) {
        printf("X");
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    FILE *file;

    if (file = fopen("~/.undersave", "r")) {
        // Do some code that I haven't written yet
    }
    else {
        char path[KILOBYTE] = "";
        printf("It seems that this is your fist time using UNDERSAVE.\nWe just need to go through some quick installation steps.\nWhere do you want your UNDERTALE save folder to be located? >>> ");
        m();
        fgets(path, KILOBYTE, stdin);
        /*
              The fault happens here, when it asks me, 
              i put in the input like normal, but
              when I press enter, I get a fault before
              it prints 'X'
         */
        m();
        mkdir(path, 0777);
        m();
        file = fopen("~/.undersave", "w");
        m();
        fprintf(file, "%s", path);
        m();
        fclose(file);
    }
      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re "*The 'm()' is so i know what line the fault happens on*", oof. Learn to use a debugger. `gdb` can easily give you a stack trace (the command is `bt` IIRC). But also, you should find `-fsanitize=address` very useful if you're using `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: `printf` uses buffered output, so you won't see anything unless you flush the output buffer. Typically, you just use a newline (`'\n'`) at the end of the printf to do that. I'd recommend `void m(int location) { printf("X%d\n", location); }` and then change the calls to `m(1)`, `m(2)`, etc.

Comment: Also see [how to remove the newline that fgets puts in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely both calls to `fopen` fail, because on Unix-like systems `~`-expansion is a feature of the shell, and isn't applied to a program opening a file directly with `fopen` or `open`.  If you want to open a file relative to your home directory, either include the full path, or use `getenv` to read the `HOME` environment variable and construct the path within your program.  Or, better still, make the filename a command-line argument; those arguments are expanded by the shell before your program sees them, so then `~` expansion would just work.

So the `fopen` for writing returns NULL, which you don't test for (a more serious bug).  And you then try to `fprintf` to a null file pointer, which naturally crashes.

Also, your `printf("X")` is not a good diagostic, because output to a terminal is usually buffered.  The X's won't actually be written to the screen until a new line is printed, or until you try to read from stdin, or some other special conditions occur. So I suspect the program actually crashes later than you think, on the `fprintf` instead of the `fgets`. See [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin/1716621#1716621) and then put `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` in your `m()` function.

Comment: If it exists, do some code that I haven't written yet, better add that in.

Comment: Oh wait, I understand now. It's not fgets, because 'm();' has not been flushed. The real problem is on 'fprintf(file,"%s",path);', the reason the folder was not created is that the path does not exist. (~ not existing) so i just assumed it was fgets stopping it.